# Listing excel tables with OleDbConnection::GetOleDbSchemaTable()

Tags: excel, ado.net, oledb

The following PowerShell snippet will list all worksheets and named ranges in an excel spreadsheet via [OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbconnection.getoledbschematable.aspx):

```
$file = "C:\Users\zippy\Documents\Foo.xlsx";
$cnStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=`"$($file)`";Extended Properties=`"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES`";";


$cn = New-Object System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection $cnStr;
$cn.Open();

# to list the sheets
$worksheets = $cn.GetOleDbSchemaTable([System.Data.OleDb.OleDbSchemaGuid]::Tables,$null);
$cn.Close();
$cn.Dispose();
$worksheets | Format-List;
```

This will however, not list tables (called lists in Excel 2003), or a named range that refers to a list.

If I pass an [OleDbSchemaGuid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbschemaguid.aspx) of type Procedures or Views I get a [MethodInvocationException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.management.automation.methodinvocationexception%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with a message of `Operation is not supported for this type of object.`

Is this possible to list the tables by tweaking with the connection strings or restrictions parameter?

Comment: I had a similar problem in a C# WinForms app.  I know it's different code, but still this might help.  When calling GetOleDbSchemaTable, and looking at the tables, you'll notice that you get more than just Worksheets - it also returns internally used tables, like filter tables, etc.  I've seen the "Operation is not supported for this type of Object" message when trying to do things with an Excel internal table.  See this post...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654433/how-to-get-list-of-only-excel-worksheet-names-in-excel-using-oledb-filter-out-n

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple source:

```
  using (var connection = (OleDbConnection)GetConnection())
        {
            connection.Open();

            var dt = connection.GetSchema("TABLES");
            var list=dt.Select().Where(w => w["TABLE_NAME"].ToString()).ToList();

            //TODO:
        }
```