# OleDbConnection.GetOleDbSchemaTable for .xlsx doesn't identify hidden worksheets

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, oledbconnection

I'm using the OleDbConnection to retrieve data from a .xlsx workbook. When I retrieve a list of worksheets it doesn't identify if any of them have been hidden. This used to be the case by ending it's name with an underscore eg "Sheet1$_". Do you know how to tell if this is hidden now?

```
                using (var connection =
                new OleDbConnection(string.Concat("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Mode=Read;Data Source=",
                    fileName,
                    ";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;IMEX=1\"")))
            using (var command = new OleDbCommand("", connection))
            {
                connection.Open();
                var listedSheets = connection.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables,
                    new object[] {null, null, null, "Table"});

                if (listedSheets != null)
                {
                    var sheetNames = new List<string>(listedSheets.Rows.Count);

                    foreach (DataRow row in listedSheets.Rows)
                    {
                        sheetNames.Add(row[2].ToString());
                    }

                    return sheetNames;
                }

                return new List<string>();
            }
```

Comment: I am confused, do you get the hidden sheets but you want your code to flag them as hidden, or you don't get them at all ?

Comment: All the sheets are returned with no indication which ones are hidden.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get list of ONLY excel worksheet names in Excel using OLEDB; filter out non-worksheets that show up in metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654433/how-to-get-list-of-only-excel-worksheet-names-in-excel-using-oledb-filter-out-n)

Comment: Excel files aren't databases. The Access OLEDB driver can't return sheet properties. The easiest *and* cross-platform solution would be to use a library like EPPlus to inspect the file's worksheets

Answer (score -1):

I think `GetOleDbSchemaTable` is not the best option here

Because it returns DataTable object regardless the datasource that might be Excel, Access, or something else. So, it is not aware of any of Excel sheet properties

Rather, you can use Excel com components to have full control on your Excel file

**Steps**

1. Add Microsoft Excel COM reference to your project
2. Add the below line to your application

   using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
3. Read the `Visible` property of the loaded sheet

**Sample Code**

```
private static Excel.Workbook MyBook = null;
private static Excel.Application MyApp = null;
private static Excel.Worksheet MySheet = null;
static void ReadExcel()
{
    MyApp = new Excel.Application();
    MyApp.Visible = false;
    MyBook = MyApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\test.xlsx");
    MySheet = (Excel.Worksheet)MyBook.Sheets[1];

    if (MySheet.Visible == Excel.XlSheetVisibility.xlSheetHidden)
    {
        //handle hidden sheet here
    }
}
```

**Notes:**

Selecting the correct COM reference may depend on your Visual Studio version
[Check this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285880/how-to-reference-microsoft-office-interop-excel-dll)

Also, [This article is a good reference](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/696864/Working-with-Excel-Using-Csharp)

Comment: ًWhen you down vote, you have to justify in a comment to improve the answer

Comment: @VSP, so how do you answer this question?

Comment: Trying to guess Excel properties from the OLEDB schema is indeed a bad idea. Using COM interop requires Excel itself though. A better option would be to use a library like EPPlus, ClosedXML or NPOI to inspect sheets and their properties